# I am facing error with my internet connection

Tags: 16.04, dns

[image]

Suddenly my connection is lost

[image]

Comment: What are your DNS servers. try changing them to something like: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `host google.com` and `host google.com 8.8.8.8`? If *neither* produce a positive result, please also add the output of `ping -c4 8.8.8.8`. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I've had this issue many times on new machines and I never know how to prevent it. But here's your fix.

Open `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` with root privileges:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

And comment out this line:

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

So it reads:

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

Then run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

This will cause `NetworkManager` to update your DNS server, instead of it referencing your machine for the DNS server.

Comment: clear or not clear but it works!

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 this file doesn't contain this line, alas.