# Ubuntu 16.04 losing DNS after waking from sleep

Tags: networking, 16.04, suspend

After one of the latest updates, I've encountered a few issues. The most impractical is that when I wake up my laptop from sleep, the wifi reconnects, but none of the services can connect (browsers, instant messaging, email, etc.) The error message I get varies from service to service.

Firefox tells me it's a DNS resolution issue. No amount of restarting wifi, ifdown/ifup etc. will restore connectivity. I have to do a complete reboot to be able to reconnect.

Has anyone encountered this? If not, where do I begin troubleshooting?

Comment: Is your DNS set to an internal or external DNS server?

Comment: @hamiheim It's DHCP, so external?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am facing error with my internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903652/i-am-facing-error-with-my-internet-connection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've encountered this issue plenty of times. If you can ping 8.8.8.8 but not google.com, this is your fix.

https://askubuntu.com/a/903671/676362

Comment: That's exactly my issue. I'll give it a try and get back to you