# How to open a file with "sudo"?

Tags: sudo

[Answer on Question - I am facing error with my internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/a/903671/665251)

Above is the link to a fix to help with a loss of connection after power saving mode. It says "open with sudo..."
How does one do that if one is a complete novice and knows nothing?

Comment: That means open that file with say the text editor `nano` but ensure you use `root powers` to edit it or it won't save. How, do: `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. This is necessary  because that file can only be edited by one with `root power`

Answer (score 18):

The answer you provided in the link wants you to open a file with root privileges, which can be achieved using these two commands

```
sudo nano /path/to/your/file.foo
```

in the command above you are opening `file.foo` in a command based text editing tool called [nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/), In your particular case this command should work.

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

## or

```
gksu gedit /path/to/your/file.foo
```

In this command you're opening the same file with a GUI based text editor called [Gedit](https://gedit.en.softonic.com/) (default on Ubuntu and Ubuntu GNOME), In your particular case, this command should work

```
gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

**Note**

Use `sudo` for command line programs (like `nano`), but use `gksu` or `gksudo` for GUI programs, which often use configuration files in the home directory. If you use plain sudo, the root user can take ownership or your user ID's configuration files and the program used that way will stop working (unless you continue using `sudo`). An alternative to `gksu` and `gksudo` is `sudo -H`

---

An explanation for *commenting out* is to add a hash `#` sign in front of the line, in the example you gave, the line

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

should become

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

Comment: Thanks! I see now that I'm still clueless as to how to continue. To "Comment Out" do I just delete the line and then hit Alt X to exit? Sorry. I'm a total newb.

Comment: Isn't `sudoedit` the preferred method to edit configuration files?

Comment: @Summet Deshmukh. No need; your answer is fine.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh the editor it opens can be configured. It can be Vim, nano, gedit, sed, true, or whatever you want it to be.

Comment: To make it slightly more confusing, if you are using Ubuntu GNOME (or I guess Ubuntu 17.10 when comes out, which will use GNOME) and are using the "GNOME on Wayland" session option you will not be able to use `sudo -H gedit` - because Wayland has stricter security policies and won't allow root to own a window in a non-root session. A workaround is to log out, then log in using the non-Wayland option.

Comment: Use `sudo` for command line programs (like `nano`), but use `gksu` or `gksudo` for GUI programs, which often use configuration files in the home directory. If you use plain `sudo`, the root user can take ownership or your user ID's configuration files and the program used that way will stop working (unless you continue using sudo). An alternative to `gksu` and `gksudo` is `sudo -H`

Comment: @sudodus could I add that **exact** comment as a side note in my answer?

Comment: Yes, if you wish :-)

Comment: @sudodus whatever improves the answer, right? ;)

Comment: @sudodus You are right that one should not use sudo with GUI programs. However, `gksu/gksudo` has been deprecated and is not installed by default. I recommend using `pkexec`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root/868882#868882 Sumeet, feel free to add the text from and link this answer.

Comment: @user68186, gksu/gksudo are still installed by default in many (all?) community flavours of Ubuntu. And they are easy to install, but you are right, it is possible to use `pkexec` and several people recommend it (you are not alone). But there is another recommendation too: "Do not use GUI application programs for elevated permissions. Use command line." But I know that many people prefer GUI programs. And GUI programs that must use elevated permissions have a built-in system, that prompt a password window, for example 'Synaptic'.

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default/284717#284717

Answer (score 5):

That means open that file with say the text editor nano but ensure you use root powers to edit it or it won't save. How, do:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

This is necessary because that file can only be edited by one with root   privilege. You will be asked for your password which you have to give so the file will open in `nano editor`.

After editing it to save it:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>
2. <kbd>enter</kbd>
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>